# Python3.2 - ImportError: No module named setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools

When I run "sudo python3.2 setup.py install" I repeatedly get the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                         
File "setup.py", line 3, in module                                                     
from setuptools import setup                                                                
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

I've installed setuptools using apt-get, removed it & then manually installed by doing the following:

```
wget http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/s/setuptools/setuptools-0.x.tar.gz           
tar zxvf setuptools-0.x.tar.gz                                                           
cd setuptools-0.x                                                                        
python setup.py build                                                                       
python setup.py install
```

I can't figure out why I'm still getting the error after repeated installations?

Comment: Forgot to add that I already tried virtualenv too: virtualenv -p /path/to/python??

Comment: For 3.x use the [distribute](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/distribute) fork. In Debian/Ubuntu the package `python3-setuptools` is actually distribute.